# Recommendation working method about open and close 3rd party software from my program

Tags: android

i open Third-party software from my program like:

```
Intent i2 = new Intent();
                 PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                 i2 = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.3rd.program"); 
                 i2.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                 startActivity(i2);
```

when this program close i need to do something in my program.

How to identify that program close and return to my program ?

Comment: Your activity will fire `onResume()` when the other program is closed. *If* the other program is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looking for `startActivityForResult` are you?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

> **public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)**
>
> *Added in API level 16*
>
> Launch an activity for which you would like a result when it finished. When this activity exits, your onActivityResult() method will be called with the given requestCode

Answer (score 0):

> How to identify that program close

You don't, any more than when your Web page links to another Web site, that you find out where the user goes after that.

> and return to my program

Your activity that called `startActivity()` will go through normal lifecycle methods (e.g., `onResume()`) when it returns to the foreground. However, bear in mind that the user can leave the other app and not return to yours, such as by pressing the HOME button.